# SSRS Open sub report with provided parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

I have a report which has 5 parameters and i want to open another report from this report which has 13 paramaters.
When i try to open this report it says some parameters are missing.
I want to know if it is possible like, if i do not pass parameters then it should ignore these parameters in repport and also in SQL query (all these are multivalue parameter).
I cannot use "allow null values" as these are multivalue parameter.

[This is main report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWHxK.png)

[These are parameters in sub report which i want to call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJEoY.png)

Can someone help me please? or i need to create seperate subreport with exact parameters everytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common ways of doing this.

**Populate parameters with a list default values**
In your subreport, taking @service as an example. If you can get a list of services from your database then create a dataset tat gives a list of distinct services, use this as the default value for your parameter. Then when you do not pass anything from the main report, the subreport will use all services.

**Set the default parameter value to a fixed constant**
The other option is to set the subreport parameters to a default value such as `*all` and then handle this when it is passed to your subreport's dataset query.

So the dataset query might be something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM myTable
  WHERE location in (@location)
    AND (service = '*All' OR service IN(@Service)
```

Comment: Thank you so much..  i had not set default values for these parameters so it was not working. Now i have set it and its working as expected. Thank you so much for help

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark below the vote up/down buttons). Thank you

Comment: i get error while voting: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.